# any place where I can learn CS math, preferably for absolute begginers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

I would like to know if there is a video, course or book(the option I would like the least) for most important topics in math for CS, I tried MIT's course is that just the best option? or is there a easier place to learn?

Comment: CS is computer science? This is a huge topic, you will need to be more specific.